# How Can I Calculate Standard Deviation (step-by-step) in R?

Tags: r, standard-deviation

How can I calculate Standard Deviation, step-by-step, in R? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the formula for standard deviation? Can you elaborate on 'step by step'?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I believe do! I'm trying to calculate sd for a specific data set. I am aware that I can simply use the sd function, but I need to calculate the standard deviation of a data set "by hand," using R. These are the values: [1] 179 160 136 227 217 168 108 124 143 140 309 229 181 141 260 203 148 169 213 257 244
[22] 271 243 230 248 327 329 250 193 271 316 267 199 171 158 248 423 340 392 339 341 226
[43] 320 295 334 322 297 318 325 257 303 315 380 153 263 242 206 344 258 368 390 379 260
[64] 404 318 352 359 216 222 283 332

Thank you!

Comment: $variance = \frac{sum((x-mean(x))^2)}{(length(x)-1)}$

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
> a <- c(179,160,136,227)
> sd(a)
[1] 38.57892
> sqrt(sum((a-mean(a))^2/(length(a)-1)))
[1] 38.57892
```

```

Answer (score 2):

So, you want to calculate the standard deviation step-by-step. So, firstly, you should calculate the sum of the differences of all data points with the mean.

Have a variable called `count` and set it to the value 0.

For that, you loop through the data set with a variable, say `i` and subtract `i` every time with the mean. Mean can be calculated as `mean(dataset)`.

Add the result of every loop iteration to count, by `count = count + (i-mean)^2`

Now, divide the count variable by `len(dataset) - 1`

The result is the variance. So, for calculating the standard deviation, you have to square root the above value.

In R, you do this as: `sqrt(variance)`

Finally, the result you get after applying the square root is the Standard Deviation.

Comment: "+=" is not an operator in R

Comment: Glen_b Thank you.  Edit done.

Was going with the pseudo algo format.